# How to associate a list workflow to list-specific (not site) content type

Tags: list, workflow, content-type

I am trying to make a workflow for a specific list content type. Unfortunately, there seems to be no option to do so. I can create a list workflow in SP Designer but can't find an option to associate with one of that lists' content types. Moreover, if I go straight to the content type I want to associate the workflow to, there is no option to actually create a workflow in SP Designer for that content type, although I can see a blank window for "a list of workflows associated with this content type".

Finally, if I get out of Designer and go to the content type in SharePoint, I can indeed "Add" a workflow to the list content type, but it will only allow me to select from about 5 stock default workflows and I cannot create a new one. If I try to create a new one that is "globally reusable", the button to promote to global is also grayed out.

So far all dead ends. Any advice for what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the top level and create a "Reusable Workflow" and from there you can add it to a content type of your choice. This is because content types are at the root of the site collection.

Look at the instructions here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608128(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I also tried that, and what happens is that I cannot associate it with the content type that I want. I can see a list of available content types and the one from my list is not there. The closest it gets is a content type that is the parent of the one I want. Why is this?

Comment: Is your content type on the root level? That's probably why you can't see it. Make the content type not on a site or sub site but on the site collection level.

Comment: The content type is for only a particular list, so no. I could re-create it at the root level but I thought that would defeat the purpose of having it be part of my list. I also have an InfoPath form that uses it so it would probably require redesigning all of that.

Comment: What purpose is it for creating this workflow for a content type if you only need it for a specific list?

Comment: Why not make a workflow for that specific list?

Comment: The list contains multiple content types, and I need the workflow to behave differently for each content type, not any list item. Do you mean that it's possible to do the same for a list using site-level content types?

Comment: Using site-level content types will fix your problem.